# from django.db import utils ImportError cannot import name utils?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, importerror

I am in the plain python shell and I am getting this error when trying to import my project models:

```
from results.models import TestResult  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 3.2\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>  
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter  
  File "C:\Users\audrey_moreau\myProject\results\models.py", line 1, in <module>  
    from django.db import models  
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>  
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])  
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__  
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)  
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__  
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])  
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 54, in load_backend  
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)  
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module  
    __import__(name)  
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 14, in <module>  
    from django.db import utils  
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to fix this? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Have you created your own package or module called 'utils' which could be causing an odd conflict? Not convinced reinstalling Django is the answer as its clearly found the django.db.utils file. The stack trace shows that its executing code in there.

Comment: Have you set environment properly? You say you're in plain python shell, but to use django models you need to be inside django shell or configure your shell to work.

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/7866256/django-circular-import-error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug and it was caused by django_nose. I was trying to import django_nose from settings.py to determine if it exists on the system like this:

```
try:
    import django_nose
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_nose']
    TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
except ImportError:
    pass
```

I modified this to

```
from imp import find_module
try:
    find_module('django_nose')
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_nose']
    TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
except ImportError:
    pass
```

and my issue was resolved...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the exact reason, but using Django's python shell i.e {$./manage.py shell} does not throw the error. I think Django does it's own little customization/overriding of python's packages, hence the altercation in the traditional interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  Uninstalling and reinstalling django took care of it:

```
sudo pip uninstall django
sudo pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

add django to your sys path. I had a similar issue and it worked for me.